# How to set text background color in wxTreeListCtrl

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Anyone know a way to set the text background colour in a wxWidgets wxTreeListCtrl?

Comment: If you tried `SetBackgroundColour()` and it didn't work for you, you should really mention this. And if you didn't try... why didn't you?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/17040#ticket

Long answer: If you really want to be able to do this, you'll need to derive your own class from wxTreeListModel and override wxDataViewModel::GetAttr() to set the item colors. wxTreeListModel is not public, so you'd have to change that in wxWidgets. Alternatively, you could copy the whole wxTreeListModel source to your project, rename it and modify it there. Both are messy, see short answer #1.